# Are prototype beans with constructor parameters an anti-pattern?

Tags: dependency-injection, spring

Reading on this, Misko Hevery has said [“Newables can ask for other Newables in their constructor, but not for Injectables”](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/)

Now it appears to me that requesting a prototype be instantiated at run-time by e.g. a Spring Container via `ApplicationContext.getBean`, passing it arguments to be added as constructor arguments, is conceptually equivalent to new-ing up an object in code with constructor arguments i.e. dependencies at run-time.

Recently in Spring some syntactic sugar in the form `@Lookup` allowing parameters to be passed to the constructor stemming from an initiative described in [a blog](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2010/08/creating-prototype-spring-beans-on.html) has been introduced to make this easier.

Does having a DI container like Spring do the work behind the scenes avoid running afoul of Misko's rule: “Newables can ask for other Newables in their constructor, but not for Injectables”?

For the record I agree this greatly aids testability. But is there any support for this assertion beyond Misko Hevery's blogging?

Should scoped prototype objects constructed at run-time with constructor arguments be avoided or made use of sparingly?

I'm not interested in whether not to based on it being likened to a Service Locator but rather due to Misko Hevery's rule mentioned.

Comment: anti-attern is an anti-pattern.  Perhaps we *are* running aFowler.

Comment: corrected spelling of afoul :)